# Algunos archivos luego de aplicar Laravel Mix no funcionan

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

He aplicado Laravel Mix, pero al parecer algunos archivos no funcionan a pesar de haber puesto las rutas de esos archivos en el Webpack.

Me doy cuenta de que los iconos y los java scripts no funcionan en mi app. Si los importo sin usar Laravel Mix si funcionan.

Este es la configuración de mi webpack:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi se ve mi app, vean que los iconos no son visibles ni tampoco las funcionalidades del javascript.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me da ningun error al iniciarlos con npm

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Que error muestra la consola de tu navegador?, si todo compila bien el error deberia de estar en alguno de los archivos. yo quitaria uno a uno, comprobando el funcionamiento correcto hasta encontrar el error. Pero seria mas facil si la consola de navegador tiene algo.

Comment: No me da ningún error, todo compila bien. Se me hace extraño que no funcione bien.

Comment: Si estas añadiendo  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/plantilla.css') }}"> y <script srx="{{ asset('js/plantilla.js') }}" />

Comment: Si Alberto, tengo añadidos los enlaces correspondientes a los archivos compilados por Laravel Mix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucione. Tenia un error de escritura en las ubicaciones que escribir en el webpack.

Comment: Entonces se puede interpretar como un typo el origen de la falla